# How to handle multi teams-In suite CRM

Tags: suitecrm

here is my doubt.
issue:
we have three teams each team have their respective head.so i want to assign all the members of the team to their respective head and when the head of the team opened his suitCRM dash board he must see only his supporting team and same for the other two cases.
when i am trying to create that hierarchy using suiteCRM it is not happening
can anyone help me out

Comment: There is way too little information here to get a chance for a good answer. You should provide context by means of some code you are trying to run, and about some parts of which you are unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 security groups for each of the 3 heads and assign individual team members to that security group.
For the case of ACl, go to the Admin > ACL Roles, create 2 different roles i.e

1. Team Head
2. Team Member

For the Team head, assign the role to the Head of the team and give necessary module access according to group, so they can only access information of individual team members under their security group.

For Team Member, assign owner ACL, so they can only see their own activities and not other team members activities or set it as group for Team activities based on your requirement.